# getting object object in return angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, json

How to access `locfrnd` in the following code
I have made an Array `PlaceCollection` which has 2 elements

1. `place`
2. `locfrnd` which is an array

I tried accessing `place` and was able to access it but for `locfrnd` I am getting the below error

```
var ctry = $scope.country;
var frnds = [];

angular.forEach($scope.Friend, function (friend) {
    var eachFriend = {
        name: friend
    }
    frnds.push(eachFriend);
});

var record = {
    place: ctry,
    locFrnd: frnds
}

$scope.placeCollection.push(record);

//I am getting object object from the following code
for (var j = 0; j < $scope.placeCollection.length; j++) {
    alert($scope.placeCollection[j].locFrnd);
}
```

Comment: try `alert ($scope.placeCollection[j].locFrnd.name);`

Comment: .locFrnd[j] - this ia also an array

Comment: Hi Geroge!
 I am getting undefined now after using the above expression.

Comment: Use $scope.placeCollection[j].locFrnd[j].name as locFrnd is also an array

Comment: Hi stx I tried this combination as well

Comment: I tried this as well

Comment: alert ($scope.placeCollection[j].locFrnd[j]);

Comment: locFrnd[j].name, sorry, like Knitesh said

Comment: @Arunroy Hello, the reason you're getting `"object, object"` is because when you call `alert()` it will internally handle arrays by calling `.join()` (Joins strings together) which when done on an array of objects (when you turn an object to a string it will just become "object") will result with `"object, object"`. Depending on what you're doing you'll most likely want another loop inside the first one :)

Comment: @Knitesh your solution worked thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try `JSON.stringify` like below:

```js
var arr = [{place: 'ABC', locFriend: 'XYZ'}, {place: 'abc', locFriend: 'xyz'}];
alert(JSON.stringify(arr));
```

Your `locFrnd`is an array and when you do an alert on array, you would get [objcet Object].

Answer (score 0):

This should also work

```
   for (var j = 0; j < $scope.placeCollection.length; j++) {
        var locFrndArray = $scope.placeCollection[j].locFrnd;
            locFrndArray.map(function(item){
                                            alert(item.name })
                                         }
}
```